# SQL server full join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

I have a full join sql query and i am retrieving the data from the same table.the problem is i am getting the null value where i am expecting the column name.

Example:
I am having a table where there are two columns typeOfPost,dob.

```
DOB               TypeOfPost
---------      --------------
20/11/1998      Manager
1/1/2000         Sales
13/6/1999         Manager
20/1/1987         Manager
1/11/1985         Sales
```

Now when I am writing a join query like

```
select DATENAME(month,dob) as Red,count(TypeOfPost) 
from tablename
where TypeOfPost='Manager'
group by DATENAME(month,dob) as A



full join

select DATENAME(month,dob) as Green,count(TypeOfPost) 
from tablename
where TypeOfPost='Sales'
group by DATENAME(month,dob) as B on B.Green = A.Red



Output--                                                Expected Output--
---------------------                           ---------------------
Month      Man      Sal                           Month      Man      Sal
--------   -----   ------                        --------   -----   ------
January      1         1                              January      1         1
NULL         1         NULL                           June         1         NULL
November   1         1                              November   1         1
```

Now here the problem rise, I want 'June' in the column Month instead of NULL value.
So is there any way to get that??
Help me out. 
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you better use 'Manager' LEFT JOIN 'Sales' ? Because Sales don't have Juni.

Comment: it will not solve my problem Daggeto b'coz this is just a sample data i have shown here.Actual data is too large where so many NULL values appear.

Comment: So i think you need one more table where will be only months. And you can join then rest tables to new one by months? mm?

Comment: The query you've posted can't possibly give you the output you mention. You should post your real query or make sure the query you post actually runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to

- use a `CASE` statement in a subselect
- Determine for given record if it is a manager or sales
- substitute with 1 or 0 accordingly
- `SELECT` and `GROUP` from this subselect the final results.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  Month
        , SUM(Man) AS Man
        , SUM(Sal) AS Sal
FROM    (        
          SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DOB) AS Month
                  , CASE WHEN TypeOfPost = 'Manager' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Man
                  , CASE WHEN TypeOfPost = 'Sales' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Sal
          FROM    tableName
        ) g          
GROUP BY
        Month
```

or

```
SELECT  Month
        , SUM(Man)
        , SUM(Sal)
FROM    (        
          SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DOB) AS Month
                  , COUNT(TypeOfPost) AS Man
                  , 0 AS Sal
          FROM    tableName
          WHERE   TypeOfPost = 'Manager'
          GROUP BY
                  DATENAME(MONTH, DOB)
          UNION ALL         
          SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DOB) AS Month
                  , 0 AS Man
                  , COUNT(TypeOfPost) AS Sal
          FROM    tableName
          WHERE   TypeOfPost = 'Sales'
          GROUP BY
                  DATENAME(MONTH, DOB)
        ) g
GROUP BY
        Month
```

Comment: One more question prerak if i want the count of manager and sales in other column then how would i get??

Example--
Total Count
-------------
    2
    1
    2

in the above case.

Comment: @Stone Cold - the easiest would be to just add a `SUM(Sal + Man)` to the outer select statement.